# How to disable mouse click event on cells of JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouseevent, tablecelleditor

I am validating a particular column of JTable. My requirement is that all the cells of that column should allow only alphabets.I have added keylistener to object of Jtable and written some logic as follows:

```
public void keyTyped ( KeyEvent e ) {

    if(!(e.getKeyChar()>='a' &&e.getKeyChar()>='z')) {
        getToolkit.beep();
    } 
}
```

Initially when focus is on cell and type something the key event is triggered fine, but when I click on the same cell and type, the key event is not getting trigerred. So I decided to disable the mouse click event on JTable. How can I disable the mouse click event on cells of JTable?

Comment: I have tried removeMouseListener() method of Jtable,but i didnt find any difference

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish ? disabling mouse events sounds like a weird thing to try to do. a mouse click happens when a user clicks trying to stop that would mean you need to seriuosly manipulate how java handles events and that sounds a bad idea.

Comment: My understanding of "validating" is somewhat different from what you describe, svkwenky. Intuitively I'd let the user type anything he/she wants but show an error on evaluation failure. That will happen for example when the cell exits edit-mode.

Answer (score 2):

Simply set a specific cell editor on that column that will not allow to input incorrect characters. And to be sure, I would also verify the input in your `TableModel` by overriding properly `setValueAt(Object, int, int)`:

Here is an example that only allows chars from A to Z and a to z:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

public class TestTable {

    private static final String ALPHA_ONLY_REGEXP = "\\p{Alpha}*";
    private static final String NONALPHA_REGEXP = "[^\\p{Alpha}]+";
    private int ALPHA_ONLY_COLUMN_INDEX = 2;

    protected String validateAndFixString(String string) {
        if (!string.matches(ALPHA_ONLY_REGEXP)) {
            string = string.replaceAll(NONALPHA_REGEXP, "");
        }
        return string;
    }

    protected void initUI() {
        final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {
            @Override
            public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
                if (column == ALPHA_ONLY_COLUMN_INDEX) {
                    if (aValue != null) {
                        aValue = validateAndFixString((String) aValue);
                    }
                }
                super.setValueAt(aValue, row, column);
            }
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            model.addColumn("Col-" + (i + 1));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (j == ALPHA_ONLY_COLUMN_INDEX) {
                    row.add("AlphabetOnly");
                }
                row.add("New cell - " + (j + 1));
            }
            model.addRow(row);
        }
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        JTextField alphaOnly = new JTextField();
        ((PlainDocument) alphaOnly.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
            @Override
            public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
                string = validateAndFixString(string);
                super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
            }

            @Override
            public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
                text = validateAndFixString(text);
                super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
            }
        });
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(ALPHA_ONLY_COLUMN_INDEX).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(alphaOnly));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestTable.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
        frame.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTable().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe disabling mouse events is not such a good idea. As you did not explicitly say, i don't know what you want to achieve; you can try some of the following:

1. Disable the table itself: `table.disable();`
2. Make cells not editable (on the table model):

   public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
    {
       return false;
    }

And if you must disable mouse events, maybe try to add a mouse listener that does nothing at all:

```
table.addMouseListener(java.awt.event.MouseAdapter  
  {  
    public void mouseClicked( java.awt.event.MouseEvent e)  
    {  
      // do nothing...  
    }  
  });
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: but after clickng on the cell,if we type numbers,they are getting added to contents of the cell,which is against my logic written in keylistener.

Comment: then do both cell disabling and empty mouse listener

Comment: Put e.doit=false in the mouseClicked method.

Comment: ok i will try and let you know.Thank you very much acostache and  GGeorge for your responses...

Comment: you just updated your answer; i think you are trying to workaround the core of the problem; maybe you should just try to use keylisteners (and play with the focus related to the cells and the table), like suggested in another answer here

Answer (score 0):

you need to add that keylistener to your editor.

once editing start the focus in in that editor and no longer on your jtable.

Comment: not never to add KeyListener to Swing JComponent without really importantn reason, nor to the JTable, please to delete this answer

Comment: value for `JTextComponents` (its derived Editor in `JComboBox`, `JSpinne`r ...) can be inserted from ClipBoard, `KeyListener` accepting only single char not arrays of chars, exactly job for `DocumentFilter`, `DocumentListener`, `KeyListener` is low level notifiers designated for prehistoric `AWT Components` and for Swing replaced with `KeyBindings`, but please to see one of important reasons for [KeyListener in JComboBox, because those events aren't finalized untill popup is visible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7984692/714968), be sure that should be replaced with `ListSelectionListener`